# Meaning of finish

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

In football context, does "finish" mean kick?

> 59' A powerful **finish** from Anel to double our lead at the Lane! 
> The centre back meets a Doyle corner on the volley and smashes past Lumley from close range. Half an hour to go.

#SUFC 2-0 #RFC

https://twitter.com/SheffieldUnited/status/1564705103625478147?s=08

Comment: In the US "finish" would generally be taken to mean the last notable play of the game.

Comment: Always cite your sources, please.

Comment: @Mari-LouA added, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would say: two or more people were involved in the play, and Anel made the kick into the goal.  Here, is is called the *finish* because it is at the end of the play.  (Not because it is a kick.)

Comment: but "powerful" means hard. So the translatiion would be "hard finish". It doesn't make sense. I understand it as a kick, - powerful kick. What do you think?

Comment: *Hard* is one synonym for *powerful*, but here, *very strong* fits better.

Comment: _Finish_ doesn't 'mean' _kick_, but the sense of the phrase is 'a powerful final kick'.